# Python socket handle multiple open connections

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

I need a way to handle multiple socket connections and keep the connection open (like JS socket.io do!).

I will have 20 clients (machines) and a list of servers, each client need to establish a connection with each server and I cannot support this with threading.

I already do this with a threading system but it will cost too much on my system.

My last try was with [Asyncore](https://pymotw.com/2/asyncore/) but without success on my purpose.

All results I find uses a threading based system. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `select.select` to wait for activity on multiple sockets.

Comment: "...I cannot support this with threading...". With 20 clients? Of course you can.

Comment: I'll read about it @Barmar

Comment: I had a Bottle application on the machine receiving requests by all 20 clients each 4 seconds and it gives me many Broken Pipes. Now i've setted to 7 seconds and works fine. As I want more 'real time' communication I thought that sockets would be the best thing to implement, but without threads because my machine resources are limited. (@JamesKPolk)

Comment: For I/O bound applications python threads are quite efficient. If you are having problems it's probably due to some reason *other* than the fact that you are using threads.